# Error when importing LayerNormalization from keras.layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to use LayerNormalization, which is documented here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization

When I import the module

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LayerNormalization
```

then I get the following Exception:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'LayerNormalization' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers'
```

My keras version is 2.3.1 and my tensorflow version is 1.13.1.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You are looking at the API for TF 1.15, while using 1.13

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is because of your TF version upgrade it to 1.15 or 2.0 works fine see this [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uZa2NDJE00fpTFsky6UKVwl_cixr_vgQ) notebook.

Comment: how is this an answer? The notebook has nothing but loading a dataset?